# Lineout shows plugged but no sound in Ununtu 18.04

Tags: ubuntu, audio, alsa, jack, alsamixer

If I connect my logitech speaker to rear jack of my desktop, it does not make sound but detected as a lineout (Built in). However, if I connect through the front jack, it makes sound and detected as headphone plugged in. 
I reinstall pulseaudio and alsamixer, tweaked on alsamixer to unmute and pump up volumes. Nothing changed.

Answer (score 0):

Partial answer:

Jack detection is independent of the sound output, so it's possibly a hardware problem even though it's detected as lineout.

That said, the most common solution to such a situation is something that's muted or low volume in your soundcard setup.

1) Even though you looked at `alsamixer`, look again, make sure to select the card (with <kbd>F6</kbd>) and not Pulseaudio, and make sure to use the right arrow to look at everything, even if it's not currently visible. Make sure nothing is muted (`MM`) that shouldn't be.

2) Alternatively, look at the output of `amixer -c PCH contents`, where `PCH` is the name of your card (look at `aplay -l`).

3) If nothing helps, and assuming you have an Intel HDA sound card, `cat /proc/asound/card*/codec\#*` will show the internal state of the codec, so you canfigure out if there's some node that doesn't show up as an ALSA mixer which needs adjustment.

Comment: My jack is detected as lineout, I think it should be detected as analog speaker. Problem lies here.

Comment: That may or may not be the problem, depending on if it's just a labelling mixup, or if it actually causes ALSA to activate the wrong codec nodes. But you need to look at either the mixer settings or the codec to debug this (or include this information in your question), guessing doesn't work.